# Passing Object as Argument During Button Click

Tags: excel, vba

Is it possible to send objects as arguments to a button click's subroutine? Let's say I have a button called "Clear Sheet". I want to send the ActiveSheet object to the subroutine the button click is assigned to.

Macro Name:

`TEST TEMPLATE.xlsm'!Sheet1.ClearSheet(ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet)`

Subroutine:

```
Private Sub ClearSheet(ByVal sh As Worksheet)

    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = GetLastRow(sh, 1)
    If lastRow >= 12 Then sh.Range("A12:O" & lastRow).Clear

End Sub
```

Comment: Why not just add a new subroutine that calls `ClearSheet(ActiveSheet)` and assign it to the button?

Comment: If you want to act on ActiveSheet then you don’t have to pass any sheet object and just use Range references without sheet qualification

Comment: In your routine you can use `Application.Caller`. That string should be the name of your button.

Answer (score 0):

You can call a function using an auxiliar one

```
Public sub CallClearSheet()
    call  ClearSheet(ActiveSheet)
end sub 


'use public and byref  in this function
Public Sub ClearSheet(Byref sh As Worksheet)

    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = GetLastRow(sh, 1)
    If lastRow >= 12 Then sh.Range("A12:O" & lastRow).Clear

End Sub
```